# windeployqt module QtQuick not installed

Tags: qt, qtquick2, windeployqt

Im trying to deploy a set of QT applications. On linux all applications works fine after installing all dependencies, but in windows QtQuick based applications doesn't work at all.

To deploy on windows I follow this steps:

1. Compile my project in release mode.
2. Add `mingw` to the system environment path
3. Run `windeployqt.exe --release c:\myappdir\relesase\myapp.exe`

When step 3 is finish I got a lot of dlls in the `release` folder **Qt5Quick.dll** among them. But `myapp.exe` doesn't work and didn't threw any error.
In order to get any extra information I add `console` to my *CONFIG* parameter under *myapp.pro* file and running myapp.exe by console I got this info:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:-1 module "QtQuick" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed
```

My version of QtSDK is 5.10.0 with **MinGW** so [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413086/module-qtquick-is-not-installed-error-in-release-build-with-windeployqt) doesn't work at all, I got more errors.

More over if I try to run myapp.exe without those dll in the root folder it works fine.

I been the whole day trying to find any solutions but nothing seems to work.

I'm pretty sure I missing something but I don't know whats is it.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try with passing --qmldir?

Comment: You are not missing a DLL, but QML files. Check if you have the `qml` folder in your deployed directory and check the contents. Seems they weren't deployed correctly. You can try using the `--qmldir` option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I suppose, I was missing something. `--qmldir` option is needed in order to add QtQuick modules.

`windeployqt.exe --qmldir . --release c:\myappdir\relesase\myapp.exe`

That line did the trick,

Thanks [@frank osterfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299399/frank-osterfeld) and [@Felix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3767076/felix)

Comment: Or if set as a custom build step, set: `--qmldir "%{CurrentProject:Path}" --release "%{CurrentBuild:Type}\%{CurrentProject:Name}.exe"`

Comment: Or in newer versions of Qt Creator: `--qmldir "%{CurrentProject:Path}" --%{ActiveProject:BuildConfig:Type} "%{ActiveProject:BuildConfig:Type}\%{CurrentProject:Name}.exe"`