Code runs fine in IDE, but after deployment I get: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(qq VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS QuickWidgets)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
    main.cpp
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(qq
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
else()
    add_executable(qq
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
endif()

target_link_libraries(
    qq
    PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::QuickWidgets
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(qq)
endif()

main.cpp:
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QtQuickWidgets>

#define QML_TEST R"(
import QtQuick.Controls
Button {}
)"

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    QQuickWidget qkwTest;
    qkwTest.setSource(QUrl(
        QStringLiteral("data:text/plain;,%1").
        arg(QStringLiteral(QML_TEST).toUtf8().toPercentEncoding())
    ));
    if(!qkwTest.rootObject())
        for(const auto &e:qkwTest.errors())
            QMessageBox::information(nullptr,"error",e.description());
    else
        QMessageBox::information(nullptr,QString(),"success");
    app.exit();
}

As mentioned, this code gets "success" in the IDE, but when I deploy the program (after using windeployqt), I get the error module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed.
Notice that I am not using any resource file. For one thing, the actual QML content is very small. Or I could be auto-generating it later. That's not important right now.
The point is, what should I do to avoid this error?

I think the problem is in the windeployqt step and nothing that you have shown in the question. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53160127/windeployqt-module-qtquick-not-installed

@drescherjm Thanks for your hint. Definitively, this had to do with windeployqt.
The option --qmldir alone did not work. I had to create a dummy .qml file with the same contents of QML_TEST, in the same folder of the executable, for the import process to be complete. This is due to the fact that I'm not using QML files in the project. Now it makes sense.
